# Docker php:X-fpm-stretch with apache

Tags: php, docker, apache

I have a question regarding the php-stretch docker image.

How can I get apache and php-fpm with that special stretch working? I am not able to install any php packages (libapache2-mod-php) and I am not able to find libphpX anywhere in that image. How is this image intended to be used?

Does somebody know, how I can load php with apache in the apache2.conf?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: what os are you using?

Comment: I'm using Arch Linux. De Docker runs, however I have no idea, where the libs are or where the config files can be found (even with find / -name ) i cannot find apache2.conf or httpd.conf